# Javascript: How to get URL with variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, url, url-rewriting

I need two things!
Task 1:

Actual URL(URL1):

> www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=12ab ref:name

I need to extract only this (URL2):

> www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc

How to do it?

Task 2:

Again I wanna make two links using URL2. The result should be like the following

DERIVED URL1:

> www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:home

DERIVED URL2:

> www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:nav

I want to insert two links on reg.php page, those links are 
www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:home
 & 
www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:nav

Note: in **name=abc** "**abc**" will change according to their name, so it must be fetched from URL, all other things are fixed

My Code:
Task 1:

```
<script>
alert(window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + variable);
</script>
```

Task 2:

```
<form id="links" action='' method='get'> 
<input type='hidden' name='token' id='token' value="44BB"/>
<input type="button" class='small-button' id='ref' value='home' onClick="parent.location= document.URL + 'ref:home'" />
<input type="button" class='small-button' id='ref' value='nav' onClick="parent.location= document.URL + 'ref:nav'" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: @Grevling I have added my code, but its not working

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on task 2 ?

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa I want to insert two links on reg.php page, those links are 
www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:home
 & 
www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=44BB ref:nav

Note: in name=abc "abc" will change according to their name, so it must be fetched from URL, all other things are fixed

Answer (score 0):

**For TASK 1:**

I tried here get url, trim and display.

```
var url=document.URL;

var start=url.search("www");
var end=url.search("abc");

var n=url.substr(start,end+3);

document.write(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Task 1

```
var variable = '?name=abc&token=44BB ref:home';
var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + variable;

var strPos = url.indexOf('&'); 

if (strPos > -1) {
  var finalURL = url.substring(0, strPos);

  alert(finalURL);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Task 1:**

```
var str="www.domain.com/reg.php?name=abc&token=12ab ref:name";
var n=str.split("&");
alert(n['0']);
```